# Two anchor links to same element not working

Tags: html

I have the following code

```
<h2 class="faqpage_category" id="faq_4">Envato</h2>
```

and two anchor links targeting `#faq_4`

```
<a href="#faq_4">Envato</a>
```

First link works fine, the second does nothing.

**[Example link](http://demo.nwdthemes.com/faqpage/?___store=french)**

The links in content area are working, the links in sidebar does not.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally that shouldn't be a problem. If you create a minimized example it works just fine: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/z9ogh257/)

I have inserted other anchor links to your site, and they all work fine, except those inside your sidebar `.block-content ul li`. But if I insert a link after the page has loaded, everything works just fine.

Maybe these `ul li` are generated using a script, which could cause this problem?

Comment: Yes, you are right. There was onclick function for side block that return false;  Thanks